# Sarcastic Star Wars droid mentioned in 80s (?) SF novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, droids

I have a vague memory of a novel, or possibly a shorter work, probably written in the 1980s, with a passing reference to a sarcastic droid in a recent Star Wars movie. It sounds like K-2SO in "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story", but of course the book was written long before the movie was.

The action in the novel probably takes place in the early 21st century, some decades after it was written. The fictional Star Wars movie was recent in the context of the story, not relative to the time it was written. It's *not* a Star Wars novel.

It *might* have been something in the "Dream Park" series by Larry Niven and Steven Barnes.

Can anyone identify the novel or story?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possibly [Oath of Fealty](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1450) by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle. There is [a Wikipedia page on the book here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Fealty_(novel)).

> In the near future, Los Angeles is an all but uninhabitable war zone, racked by crime, violence, pollution and poverty. But above the blighted city, a Utopia has arisen: Todos Santos, a thousand-foot high single-structured city, designed to used state-of-the-art technology to create a completely human-friendly environment, offering its dwellers everything they could want in exchange for their oath of allegiance and their constant surveillance . But there are those who want to see the utopia destroyed, whose answer to tomorrow's best and brightest hope is mindless violence. And they have just entered Todos Santos.

However if this is the correct novel droids and sarcasm references are there, but there is no mention of a *sarcastic droid*. One of the protagonists, Tony Rand, creates robots that he names after R2-D2:

> That led to his development of robot probes; small devices with cameras and sound equipment which could move freely through Todos Santos under Rand's direct control. If he sent out two or three of the small tele-operated devices (he called them Arr-twos after the small droid in Star Wars), Rand could effectively be in several places at once, see machinery and construction details in real time from both above and below, and generally explore without leaving his bedroom.

Then later there is a reference:

> "Not those, no. They don't seem to make much sense. News well, mostly in-house news, actually. Even the Tonight Show monologue was pretty cryptic last time I watched. We get movies on the cable," Tony realized suddenly. "That new guy in Star Wars Eight, the sarcastic one who keeps poking holes in Han Solo's physics?"
> "Rip Mendez. Mmm. . . maybe. He might go for it. He's got an adopted son."

The date matches since *Oath of Fealty* was published in 1981, and the book is set "*in the near future*" though I don't think an explicit date is given. Finally it is a Larry Niven book (you mentioned you thought it might be in the Larry Niven and Steven Barnes *Dream Park* books, but I have all four of those and I can't find anything matching your description).

Comment: Man, that's obscure.  Nice job! +1

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. I probably It's entirely possible that I mentally retconned the reference to be to a droid after seeing K-2SO in "Rogue One".